# registering driectshow filter on windows mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile, activex, directshow

I'm trying to register my DirectShow filter on Windows Mobile. My project has Linker/General/Register Output set to Yes. However, nothing is getting registered and I'm getting the following error:
Project : error PRJ0050: Failed to register output. Please try to register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.

I'm running Vista and UAC is disable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but my guess is that it's trying to register the WM DLL on the host system (vista) and not on the WM device.  I don't think there is a method to register the DLL on the WM Device in Visual Studio.

You can either create a CAB file, where you can indicate which DLL are self-registering or you can write a quick tool to register the DLL for you.   Both are pretty simple to do.